# Is there a concise way to specify an element name with a variable when defining an R vector with c()

Tags: r, vector, named-parameters

Suppose we are defining an R vector V with three elements whose names are "a", "b", and the value in variable x.  Is there a concise way to do it?  I.e. in the following, can ?x be replaced with something that extracts the value of x and uses it as the name?

```
V = c(a=1, b=45, ?x=100)
```

This would work:

```
V = setNames(c(1, 45, 100), c("a", "b", x))
```

But it would sure be nice if there were a way to do it without using setNames, keeping the name and data values closedly paired in the definition statement.

Comment: A slightly more concise way would be adapting your code `V <-  c(a=1, b=45, setNames(100, x))`. It still uses `setNames`, but keeps the name and data together. I realise that this isn't a large-scale solution, though...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. If `a` is taken literally, how is `c` supposed to know `x` is a variable? You will probably need to write your own `c` function in order for this to work.

Comment: Try with `dplyr` `x <- "c"; data_frame(a = 1, b = 45) %>% mutate(UQ(x) := 100) %>% unlist#
  a   b   c 
  1  45 100`  Or `V <- c(a = 1, b = 45);
V[x] <- 100`

Comment: I'd like to see an R extension that lets you do this.  It seems to me like a pretty obvious thing to want.  A double back-tick could be used, since that would never occur in regular R code, and back-tick is already used to specify special processing of argument tags:

`V = c(a=1, b=45 \`\`x\`\`=100)`

Answer (score 0):

From the R language definition:

> Each argument [in a function call] can be tagged (tag=expr), or just be a simple
>   expression. It can also be empty or it can be one of the special
>   tokens ‘...’, ‘..2’, etc.
>
> A tag can be an identifier or a text string.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> f(x)
> g(tag = value, , 5)
> "odd name"("strange tag" = 5, y)
> (function(x) x^2)(5)
> ```

There's no special syntax, as far as I know, that would make a tag to be interpreted as a symbol or general expression and replaced with its value.